# How to use onclick events when using Tabulator Ajax with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

The current dilemma is **Tabulator does not support reactive data when using ajax**. This severely limits the ability to use Tabulator on larger projects since you must have all your data locally, not good for projects that have millions of rows in a database, we all know that's not going to work.

Here is an example of formatting for the cell:

```
var nameFormat = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
   var value = cell.getValue();
   return '<a href="#" @click="openModal()">'+value+'</a>';
}
```

I would like to open a modal component from VueJS when the user clicks a link in the table, it should fire `openModal()`. But VueJS can't access the data from tabulator.

**How could this be accomplished?**

The only other option I see is, using jQuery or vanilla js to show a modal on click, but going down that road is in bad practice as I need to stay within a SPA reactive system.

I also use these options as well, which require the use of Ajax

`ajaxFiltering:true,`

`ajaxSorting:true,`

**Links for reference:**

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/data#ajax

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/reactivity

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/frameworks#vue

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is you are trying to achieve, there is no way to reactivity handle data that is stored on a remote server.

Reactive data refers to local array mainulation directly atering the DOM and vice versa, therefor it would nor be possible to do this with a remote server as there is no array reference to track.

If you have a specific task in mind please mention that and i can help you with the correct approach to achieve your goals

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the below

1. Load all the Data at once, Let VirtualDom take care of it
2. Implement Server side pagination for large data